# backgroundImage React Native not working with flatlist not showing me the images

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i need to show the images on my screen with the element flatlist

```
const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
        <ImageBackground
            source={{ uri: item.imageUrl }}
            imageStyle={{
                borderRadius: 6,
                resizeMode: 'contain'
            }}
        />
    );
    return (<FlatList data={coursesData} renderItem={renderItem} keyExtractor={(item) => item.id} />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues:

1. Why are you using ImageBackground instead of just Image?  ImageBackground is intended for use as a background.
2. If the source of your image is a url you must specify an image height and width.
3. give Flatlist style={{ flex: 1 }}, this will allow it to take up all the space it needs.

Comment: thanks it works know after i add the height and the width, i just need to add edit icon.. on the bottom of the image did you have another idea?

Comment: If you continue to use ImageBackground you could do something like:
<ImageBackground>
<View style={{ alignContent: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
<Icon .... />
</View>
</ImageBackground>

Comment: @RianHalabi can you post what you did as an answer? having the same issue